# Rebased with merge conflicts: How to undo?

Tags: git, merge, rebase, abort

I was working on a feature branch B that I had branched out from master a month ago. As other new features came in, the master branch kept getting updated.

This is how master branch looks like right now:

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 ->7
```

When I had first branched out, it looked like this:

```
1 -> 2 -> 3
```

This is how my feature branch (B) looks like right now:

```
x -> y -> z
```

Now that I am ready to push my new feature to master, I was advised to first rebase from master, and then create a PR.

While doing `git rebase`, my branch encountered a merge conflict with a couple of files. I thought I'll just keep the incoming changes and the rebase will proceed normally. However, me resolving the conflicts converted the entire "REBASE MASTER" step to a sort of "MERGE MASTER". AKA: It applied the commits that had already been merged into master into my feature branch, not something I initially intended to do with `git rebase`.

This is how my feature branch looks like right now:

```
x -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> y -> 7 -> z
```

This is what I wanted to achieve (but didn't):

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 ->7 -> x -> y -> z
```

How do I go back? This has already been pushed to the remote branch, so I can't simply delete my local branch and fetch from origin again.

One way I can think of is to branch out from master again, and create a feature branch C. Then, cherry-pick commits from B to C. Once I am sure C is a complete copy of B (and only contains the commits I want), I can delete B. Am I missing something? Or is there a better/faster way?

Comment: Your feature branch does _not_ look like what I would have expected from a simple rebase against `master`.  I say this, because commits from both branches are strewn together in a seemingly random way.  Here is what it should have looked like after the rebase: `1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 ->7 -> x -> y -> z` ... maybe you should give the _exact_ steps which happened to land you in this state.

Comment: what did you expect `rebase` to do? Do you still know the commit id of your "old" z? If yes you can check it out, its not deleted.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That is exactly what I expected git rebase to end up with as well. But because of the merge conflicts and me manually resolving them, I ended up with that history.

Comment: @Lux Can you elaborate how that can help me undo this?

Comment: If you have committed and pushed, then you can't really undo this.  You could try to use `git revert`.  Most likely, you made some serious errors during the rebase other than just resolving merge conflicts, which are a fairly common and normal thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

( First of all, just in case, abort any rebase still in progress with `git rebase --abort` )

---

Are you the only one to work on this feature branch? (I guess so, I'll assume it for the following)

Has the PR been accepted/merged into master yet?

**If not**, then it is very much an undoable situation. (This may be what Lux hinted at in comments)

First, find the commit hash you need to restore (`z` in your example). For that you can check your branch's [reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) (or maybe just pick it from your recent commands output if available).

Then restore your local branch B to the old reference (before the rebase) and push it again to the remote (with `--force`, since git will complain that this is not a linear history).

```
git branch -f B <commit_hash_of_z>
git push -f origin B
```

Now you can redo your rebase and try to figure out where it went sideways last time.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to revert a check-in, that goes as separate check-in itself.

But i would advise to proceed carefully and read in out.

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes/git-revert

Also i hope you understand the difference of "rebase A on B" and "merge A with B"

I would advise if you are doing rebase, please update the origin of master on local.(that's my trick of keeping things bit managed, I don't know if it is standard)

Comment: Sorry my bad, I missed one para, (reading from mobile). As you said you have committed it, only solution seems to be take old base and cherry pick and then check-in with desired changes. I know it's a headache.

Comment: Also what we follow is that if there are some problems in final set of code we do another check-in with "fix-A-on-B.." for us what matters is shape of code not of branches